# HTML two table row-size correlation?

Tags: html, css

I have two table class. Different `padding`, `font-size`, let just say everything is different. I put them next to each other.

Is there a way to force table2's rows to "complete" table1's rows, as per, take the exact `height` without me writing a number for `height`?

It would be convenient because `padding` and `font` are different, so if I want to make the two table look like they are one table, I have to count and calculate row `height` to make them fit.

```css
table.right1 {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-box;
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 1%;
  margin: 0px;
}

table.right1 tr:nth-child(even) {
  color: #FFB5F9;
  border-color: #000;
  background: #292929;
}

table.right1 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #292929;
  border-color: #000;
  color: #45ADFD;
}

table.sty {
  background: #000;
  border-collapse: separate;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #000;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  display: inline-box;
  width: 1%;
}

table.sty th {
  background: #292929;
  border-left: 1px solid #555;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #999;
  color: #000;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

table.sty td {
  border-right: 1px solid #000 border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-top: 1px solid #616161;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #292929;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

table.sty tr {
  background: #292929;
}

table.sty tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #292929;
  color: #C7C7C7;
}

table.sty tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #292929;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table class="right1" border="1" bgcolor="#292929" cellpadding="11" cellspacing="1" rowspan="1">
  <tbody>

    <tr height="400">
      <td>
        <div style="width: 100px;">
          <center> 1 </center>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="51">
      <td>
        <div style="width: 100px;">
          <center> 2 </center>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="51">
      <td>
        <div style="width: 100px;">
          <center> 3 </center>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="51">
      <td>
        <div style="width: 100px;">
          <center> 4 </center>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="51">
      <td>
        <div style="width: 100px;">
          <center> 1 </center>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="51">
      <td>
        <div style="width: 100px;">
          <center> 5 </center>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--------------                                         --------- ---->
  </tbody>
</table>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------- ---->


<!--__________________________CONTENT______________________________ -->

<table class="sty">
  <tbody>



    <tr height="50">
      <!--___________ 000 _____________________________ -->
      <!--------------------------------HUN------------------------------------->
      <td>
        <div style="width: 100px;">
          <center>
            lorem ipsum
            </br>

          </center>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #000 ; border-right: 1px       solid #4C82C0; "> . </td>
      <!---------------------------------ENG------------------------------------>
      <td>
        <div style="width: 110px;">
          <center>
            lorem ipsum
          </center>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #000 ; border-right: 1px       solid #4C82C0;  width=1 ;"> . </td>
      <!---------------------------------GER------------------------------------>
      <td>
        <div style="width: 110px;">
          <center>
            lorem ipsum
          </center>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #000 ; border-right: 1px       solid #4C82C0;  width=1 ;"> . </td>
    </tr>




    <tr height="300">
      <!--___________ 000 _____________________________ -->
      <!--------------------------------HUN------------------------------------->
      <td>
        <div style="width: 100px;">
          <center>
            lorem ipsum
            </br>

          </center>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #000 ; border-right: 1px       solid #4C82C0; "> . </td>
      <!---------------------------------ENG------------------------------------>
      <td>
        <div style="width: 110px;">
          <center>
            lorem ipsum
          </center>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #000 ; border-right: 1px       solid #4C82C0;  width=1 ;"> . </td>
      <!---------------------------------GER------------------------------------>
      <td>
        <div style="width: 110px;">
          <center>
            lorem ipsum
          </center>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #000 ; border-right: 1px       solid #4C82C0;  width=1 ;"> . </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I think you should add your `HTML` and `CSS` Code

Comment: it's very long...I'll try to add the important parts..

Comment: I inserted code...but it's really only about different content sizes in 2 tables....

Comment: Can you change the HTML at all? In that case you should 1) correct all the errors, and 2) put the content as two tbodies in one table.

Comment: I need the two different styles